# Rabbit-mq hangs to process message after MessageConversionException

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am using Rabbit-mq messaging broker in my application for queuing purpose. Where I will send a chunk of data to one queue, where another consumer which is listening to this queue will convert this message into an user-defined object. . Here is the consumer class code

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue-name")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
         try {
             TestObject o = (TestObject ) new TestObject().fromMessage(message);
             //do other processes
         } catch (MessageConversionException ex){
             //exception thrown
         }
```

Here for some reason, if `MessageConversionException` is thrown, then all message queue stops its process, and no queue would accept or process any messages. Is there any way to recover from exception?

Even catching this exception is not helping me.

Comment: Instead of throwing new exception  log the exception in the catch block

Comment: Still the queue hangs

Comment: Can you provide the complete code

Comment: Just handle the exception. If there is error in conversion, the ack the message in the queue so it gets deleted and then continue processing the other messages in the queue. Hope it solves your problem.